# dotnet core wrong client IP address

Tags: c#, http, ip, .net-core

I try to find client IP address with dotnet core. It's needed to find geo locations with [freegeoip.net](http://freegeoip.net) for current user. When I open this page, I got something like this: **89.190.94.34**. But my core app return wrong IP. Something like: **172.19.0.5**. My app script, for getting client address:

Simply: `this.Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()`

on localhost it is correctly `::1`

Is this script wrong? What is IP 172... and how I can get correct IP address?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should know that there are 2 types of IP adresses, pubblic and private. The public address is an address given from you ISP that can be viewed by anyone in the world having an internet connecion (also if they have another ISP), the private address is an address valid only in your LAN, so many people have the same private address in different LANs. 
Now clarifying that, the first address you wrote (89.190.94.34) is your pubblic address, and the second (172.19.0.5) is your private one.
I don't really know what you are trying to do, but I hope this helps. I reccomend you to learn more about ranges and other stuff of IPs online.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Simply need get public address of the user, who is using application. But with already mentioned command, I got private (you said). Is possible get to public IP address? :-)

Comment: No problem, you could try this: string myIp = new WebClient().DownloadString(@"http://icanhazip.com").Trim();

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: So, I still would like to ask for one thing. When I deploy app to remote server, IP address will be mine or web server? (note: The web server is running in docker container and nginx server as proxy). I think that i will not work. Or will it? Thank you

Comment: I don't have any experience with docker, sorry, but I'd say the IP will be the one on the machine running it, so if you are running it into yours, it would be the same address you got before.

Comment: Yes, I think it too. Is there way, how to get correct IP of user or i have to use for geo information for example google maps? Thank you